# Vuejs + HighchartJS xAxis width

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vuejs2

I am trying to plot a bar graph using HighchartJS. I am able to get properly when the start date is 1st Jan, Dynamically, when I change the data from 1st Jan to 2nd Jan the grouped Bar chart, where Tank 4 has values, but not displaying, Its going far left, when I select only Tank 4, I am able to see the ba graph, without selecting Tank 4 alone, how can this be achieved?

**first Graph where data begins from 1st Jan**
[image]

**Second Graph after dynamically changing data to start from 2nd Jan**
[image]

**Second Graph when only Tank 4 is selected**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you have a problem with placing columns on your chart correctly I suggest experimenting a little with different properties of the axis. You can set e.g tickInterval to day interval, you can also set minimum and maximum values for the chart. Please check them out and tell me if it helped you.

API references:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4xj73w1L/

```
xAxis: {
 type: 'datetime',
 min: new Date('2016-12-31T15:00:00Z').getTime(),
 max: new Date('2017-01-03T15:00:00Z').getTime(),
 tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
},
```